# GOPATH in declarative Jenkinsfile

Tags: go, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gopath

I'm setting up a Jenkins multibranch pipeline for our Go mono repo at work. How do I set the `GOPATH` so the go tool can find where Jenkins has fetched the repo?

I've tried setting it with the `environment` syntax, like so:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'golang:1.9.2'
        }
    }

    triggers {
        gitlab(triggerOnPush: true, triggerOnMergeRequest: true, branchFilterType: 'All')
    }

    post {
        failure {
            updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'jenkins-build', state: 'failed'
        }
        success {
            updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'jenkins-build', state: 'success'
        }
    }

    environment {
        GOPATH = "${pwd}"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'jenkins-build', state: 'pending'
                echo 'Linting...'
                sh 'go version'
                sh 'go get -u -v github.com/golang/lint/golint'
                sh 'golint -set_exit_status ./...'
                echo 'Building...'
                sh '''
                cd my_app
                go build
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `golint` command works fine as it's within the right directory, but the go build command can't find any of the other dependencies that are within the root directory. For instance running `go build` in `my_repo/my_app` it won't find any of the dependencies in `my_repo`, say `my_repo/my_dep`.

I also tried setting `GOPATH` within the build stage:

```
stage('Build') {
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'jenkins-build', state: 'pending'
                echo 'Building...'
                sh '''
                GOPATH=$(pwd)
                cd fpweb
                go build
                '''
            }
        }
```

But the same happens.

```
my_app.go:19:2: cannot find package "my_repo/my_db" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/my_repo/my_db (from $GOROOT)
    /data/jenkins_slave/workspace/my_repo-pipeline_master-JHGTBESY3LSHGFEUYYM2777JIAFVR4R7E4Y2YPZA2MI4XW6BBTQQ/src/my_repo/my_db (from $GOPATH)
```

**EDIT**: What should I set my `GOPATH` to?

**UPDATE**: when I set the `GOPATH` to the `WORKSPACE`:

```
environment {
        GOPATH = "$WORKSPACE"
    }
```

I get an error:

```
[my_repo-pipeline_master-JHGTBESY3LSHGFEUYYM2777JIAFVR4R7E4Y2YPZA2MI4XW6BBTQQ] Running shell script
+ pwd
+ // GOPATH=/data/jenkins_slave/workspace/my_repo-pipeline_master-JHGTBESY3LSHGFEUYYM2777JIAFVR4R7E4Y2YPZA2MI4XW6BBTQQ
/data/jenkins_slave/workspace/my_repo-pipeline_master-JHGTBESY3LSHGFEUYYM2777JIAFVR4R7E4Y2YPZA2MI4XW6BBTQQ@tmp/durable-18853a9e/script.sh: 3: /data/jenkins_slave/workspace/my_repo-pipeline_master-JHGTBESY3LSHGFEUYYM2777JIAFVR4R7E4Y2YPZA2MI4XW6BBTQQ@tmp/durable-18853a9e/script.sh: //: Permission denied
```

Comment: You need to put the code in your GOPATH. Unless your repo contains the complete GOPATH structure (which is not recommended), jenkins isn't going to create GOPATH for you.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, the problem is that I don't know what to set my GOPATH to. I've tried a number of different paths, and none of them work.

Comment: You can set GOPATH to whatever you want, but nothing will work until you put packages correctly in GOPATH. I don't see anything here attempting to place the packages at their full import path relative to GOPATH.

Comment: Jenkins just fetches the packages to the workspace, and I need to then manually move them? So, I have to `mv` the repo fetched by git from where Jenkins fetches it to, to wherever I set the `GOPATH`? ie. `cd .. && mv my_repo $GOPATH/src`

Comment: It's really simple.  Wherever you have your `$GOPATH` set, your repo and _all_ of its dependencies have to be located within `$GOPATH/src` (or have to be vendored within your repo).  Whether that means moving them to the Jenkins folder, or symlinking them (I _think_ that works), or vendoring them (probably the best solution), that's your call.

Comment: Oh, also note that the `$GOPATH` var can be a colon-seperated list just like the `$PATH` var (ex. `GOPATH="my/repo/path:my/normal/gopath"`).  So you can add _both_ the jenkins workspace and the normal `$GOPATH` into the var, and the go tool will check both, in order, using the first version it finds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make `$GOPATH/src/my_repo/my_db` exist. The value of $GOPATH is not really important as far as Go is concerned. `$GOPATH/src/my_repo/my_db` may be a symlink. We create that symlink as part of the test script in our CI system.

I'm not very familiar with Jenkins, but I'm going to assume that $WORKSPACE is where the code is checked out (e.g. $WORKSPACE/.git exists). In that case, see if you can execute the following script before running any go command:

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/my_repo
ln -s $WORKSPACE $GOPATH/src/my_repo/my_db
```

Again, the important thing is that `$GOPATH/src/my_repo/my_db` exists. How you make this happen is up to you.

Comment: This was the solution, adding a ` sh 'ln -sf ${WORKSPACE} ${GOPATH}/src/my_repo'` line did the trick. Many thanks!

Comment: Got mine working too. I was not understanding sym link properly.